# What is the difference between java dashed arguments (like -D) and the without a dash?

Tags: java

When we launch jar file by command line

```
$ java -jar someJar.jar arg1 arg2
```

We can pass argument by just adding arguments by space. But sometimes I faced with the arguments those start with dash like -Darg1, -Darg2.
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the `-D`, you're creating arguments that will be passed to `main` in its string array. With the `-D`, you're defining a *system property* which is accessibe from `System.getProperties` and `System.getProperty`. Some system properties have predefined meanings, such as `user.dir` which defines the user's home directory. More about "system properties" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--).

This is documented in [the tools documentation for the `java` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html):

> **`-Dproperty=value`**
>
> Sets a system property value. The property variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The value variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If value is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example `-Dfoo="foo bar"`).

Comment: Will this change the value of the property that is already defined in system environment?

Comment: I checked. It changes indeed.

Answer (score 4):

the option `-D` is for [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) it's different from arguments

try : `java -DsysProp1=value1 -DsysProp2=value2 -jar someJar.jar arg1 arg2`

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ArgsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Program Arguments:");
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println("\t" + arg);
        }

        System.out.println("System Properties from VM Arguments");
        String sysProp1 = "sysProp1";
        System.out.println("\tName:" + sysProp1 + ", Value:" + System.getProperty(sysProp1));
        String sysProp2 = "sysProp2";
        System.out.println("\tName:" + sysProp2 + ", Value:" + System.getProperty(sysProp2));

    }
}
```

Comment: What properties? Can you give more detailed information?